# Is it possible to have true transparency (without ghost shadows)?

Tags: transparency

Is it possible to have true transparency?

I have modelled a house with four walls and I want to do a section zoom where, at the beginning, I have the walls solid, but one gradually gets transparent.

I have animated a solid and a transparent material through a mix shader, but my problem is that when it's transparent the edges of the walls still have black shadows

I have tried to find some render settings that will remove those "ghost-shadows" but without any success.

I don't want the "hard clip" like the one that we get with the "restrict rendering".

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: is your transparent shader really 100% white? please check

Comment: yes it is #FFFFFF RGB:1,1,1

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your images precisely what's going on but it could possibly be due to insufficient Transparency bounces in your Render Light Paths settings. Try increasing the Max Bounces and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening here is a "[Z-fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)" between the surface of the transparent wall and that of the opaque one, meaning that since they are **overlapping exactly** along one of their faces, the render engine is confused as to which one to use for shading calculations.

One may think that a fully white transparent surface wouldn't Z-fight, ...but it does.

[image]

As a solution: remove the overlap! Move the surface a tiny bit away (or inside) the opaque wall.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Max bounce seems not to have any effect.

No2 seems to work, if I move the object so its fully free-standing it´s true trancparent. 
However I have many things to move and really dont like that approtch, must be a better way?

In a early draft I did a solution in two steps, first restrict render keyframe, and in the video-editing made a cut, extended last and first frame and a cross/blend, worked pretty good to get the effect of true trancparent to full solid in a nice blend.. But seems lika a pretty bad and messy workaround..

No way to do someting in node to use restrict render or remove the shadowa in a way that I want?

Comment: SE does not work like a forum, where there is a discussion thread. Here there are questions, and below them there are answers (and comments, but that's separate.) This here reads more like a next forum post, then an answer. Please either edit this into an answer. Or edit your question, to include the update.